# What does "?" mean in Java?

Tags: java, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I dont know what the question mark (`?`) stand for in java, I was doing a small program, a Nim-game. were looking in a book, for help and saw this statement:

```
int pinsToTake = (min >= 2) ? 2 : 1;
```

I don't understand it, what will `?` represent, can it be something to do with if-statement but you put it in a variable? and the `:` can be something "else"? (this things that I just said can be very misleading)

Comment: See [?:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> someval = (min >= 2) ? 2 : 1;

This is called ternary operator, which can be used as `if-else`. this is equivalent to

```
if((min >= 2) {
   someval =2;
} else {
   someval =1
}
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) for more info and usage.

Answer (score 8):

Its `ternary operator` also referred to as the **conditional operator**, have a look [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java)

like `Object bar = foo.isSelected() ? getSelected(foo) : getSelected(baz);`

eg. `operand1 ? operand2 : operand3`

> - if operand1 is true, operand2 is returned, else operand3 is returned
> - operand1 must be a boolean type
> - operand1 can be an expression that evaluates to a boolean type
> - operand1 and operand2 must be promotable numeric types or castable object references, or null
> - if one of operand2 or operand3 is a byte and the other a short, the type of the returned value will be a short
> - if one of operand2 or operand3 is a byte, short or char and the other is a constant int value which will fit within the other operands
>     range, the type of the returned value will be the type of the other
>     operand
> - otherwise, normal binary numeric promotion applies
> - if one of operand2 or operand3 is a null, the type of the return will be the type of the other operand
> - if both operand2 and operand3 are different types, one of them must be compatible (castable) to the other type
>     [reference](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/ternary.html)

Answer (score 4):

it means:

```
if(min >= 2) 
   someval =2;
else 
   someval =1
```

Its called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a)
See this java [example](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm) too

Answer (score 4):

That's a Ternary Operator. [Check Oracle's doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) for further info. Long story short, it is an if-else statement that can be done in a single line and used inside methods and to define variable values.

Syntax:

```
boolean_expression ? do_if_true : do_if_false;
```

Parallelism with if-else statement:

```
if(boolean_expression)
    //do_if_true;
else 
    //do_if_false;
```

I didn't use brackets on purpose, since you can only execute one line of code in `do_if_true` and `do_if_false`.

Example of use:

```
boolean hello = true;
String greetings = hello ? "Hello World!" : "No hello for you...";
```

This will set `someString` as `"Hello World!"` since the boolean variable `hello` evaluates to true. On the other hand, you can nest this expressions:

```
boolean hello = true;
boolean world = false;

String greetings = hello ? (world ? "Hello World!" : "Hello Stranger!") : "No hello for you...";
```

In this case, greetings will have as a value `"Hello Stranger!"`;

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [Ternary If operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java), it's just short-hand for an `if...else`

Answer (score 0):

"? :" is a ternary operator equivalent to an if else statement.

In your example:

```
   pinsToTake = (min >= 2) ? 2 : 1
```

if min >= 2 then assign 2 to pinsToTake, else assign  1

Answer (score 0):

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

(a > b) ? a : b; is an expression which returns one of two values, a or b.
 The condition, (a > b), is tested. If it is true the first value, a, is returned. If it is false, the second value, b, is returned.
 Whichever value is returned is dependent on the conditional test, a > b. The condition can be any expression which returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

It is called conditional operator.This is how it works.
if min is greater than or equal to 2 ,then first value after ? that is 2 here will  be assign to corresponding variable ,otherwise second value that is 1 here will be assign.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.quora.com/Java-programming-language/What-does-a-colon-and-question-mark-mean-in-Java-and-how-would-one-succinctly-explain-this-bit-of-code-to-beginners) will tell you all you need.

Summary for archival sakes:

> It's called the conditional operator.  It's a ternary operator that
>   takes three terms:
>
> BooleanExpression ? Expr1 : Expr2
>
> The BooleanExpressionis evaluated.  If it's true, the value of the
>   whole expression is Expr1.  If it's false, the value of the whole
>   expression is Expr2.
>
> So it serves the same kind of purpose as an if statement, but it's a
>   term rather than a whole statement. That means you can embed it in
>   places where you can't use a whole statement.